# Determine if two groups differ for a series of binary variables - logistic regression

Tags: logistic, binary-data, group-differences, multivariate-regression

I am trying to determine how to analyze my dataset. I have two stimulus categories (Type 1 and Type 2) and then a series of variable observations that are binary (did respond/didn't respond, did approach/didn't approach, etc).

I want to find out if the responses differed based on the stimulus type (1 or 2). I was thinking of attempting a multivariate logistic regression but I can't tell if that's the recommended way to handle this dataset. My dependent variables would be all of my binary response variables.

I don't want to build a model that would predict which stimulus type has occurred based on the response, necessarily. I just want to test if the responses differ significantly for each stimulus and I'm not sure how to interpret multivariate regression results.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by multivariate regression in this case. If you wanted to analyze all of your binary outcomes at once and as a function of the stimulus category, then this would be multivariate logistic regression (multivariate = multiple outcomes). In your question, you talk about stimulus category being your response (dependent) variable and how you don't want to predict it, which makes sense; however, that would imply a multiple logistic regression (one outcome but multiple predictors). Can you clarify the desired dependent variable(s)?

Comment: @Billy I think you're right, I think all of my binary variables would be my dependent variables and the stimulus type would be the independent variable. I will edit my question to reflect this. Would I then interpret the log odds ratio to determine if the groups are different?

Comment: The logistic regression would tell you whether the probability of the outcome differs between the two conditions. This is analogous to running a linear regression with a binary predictor to see whether there are mean differences between those two groups: just in this case, that linear regression has been transformed via the logit link function